# GraphQL Hasura - how to make mutation to insert multiple rows with multiple rows into second linked with foreign key table

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, hasura

I have two tables linked with foreign key:
"events"  and "lectures" with foreign key "event_id".
Is it possible to save in one mutation multiple events with multiple lectures for each?

I tried

```
mutation insertEvents(
    $objects: [events_insert_input!] = {
      lectures_data: {
        data: {
          event_id: null
          lecture_title: ""
          is_done: false
          is_planned: false
          order: 10
          }
      }
      datetime: "" 
      ...    
    }
  ) {
    insert_events(objects: $objects) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
```

but cannot make the lecture_data an array...

And when I try:

```
mutation insertEvents($events: [events_insert_input!]!, $lectures: [lectures_insert_input!]!) {
  insert_events(objects: $events) {
    affected_rows
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
  insert_event_lectures(objects: $lectures) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

The lectures are not getting the foreign key inserted...

The ids in the events table are auto-generated by database.

Is it possible at all? Or I need to send mutation for each event separately in forEach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually simple.
With query

```
export const INSERT_EVENTS = gql`
  mutation insertEvents(
    $objects: [events_insert_input!]!
  ) {
    insert_events(objects: $objects) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
`;
```

than (this is Apollo Client)

```
insertEvents({
        variables: {
          objects: events,
        },
      });
```

and events object just need to contain the data necessary for linked tables:

```
events = [
   {
   event1_name,
   event1_date,
   lectures_data (<-this is table name): {
      data: [
         {lecture1 data},
         {lecture2 data}
         ]
      }
   }, 
   {here second event in same format...} 
]
```